# Semantic-React: How to block required popup message for certain actions?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have a form like this.  I want the required attribute for the submit button, however when I click on the action button (for the self-implemented clipboard copy) it still signs that the fields are empty, starting with the first in order.

```
  <Form.Input
    label='Hostname'
    required={!hostname}
    defaultValue={hostname}
    onChange={e => {
      setHostname(e.target.value); 
    }}
    action={{
      color: 'teal',
      labelPosition: 'right',
      icon: 'copy',
      content: 'Copy',
      onClick: (e) => copyToClipboard(hostname)
    }}
  />
  <Form.Input
    label='User'
    required={!user}
    defaultValue={user}
    onChange={e => { 
      setUser(e.target.value); 
    }}
    action={{
      color: 'teal',
      labelPosition: 'right',
      icon: 'copy',
      content: 'Copy',
      onClick: (e) => copyToClipboard(user)
    }}
  />
```

[image]

Even clicking on the copy action created for the user it still asks for the previous empty field in a popup message. The copy function runs without a problem, but I don't know how could I block this message for any non-submit actions.